# Angular : How to compile a directive from a link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive with this link function:

```
link : function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
         var markdownContent = {};    
         markdownContent.result = element.text();
         markdownContent.result += '<button ng-click="console.log("test")" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>'; 
                    }
        element.html(markdownContent.result);
```

The trouble is that the ng-click directive isn't working.

I am pretty sure that the problem is that I need to compile for say to angular that I need to check this element. But I don't understand the syntax and the process...

If someone can help me it will be great!

**EDIT : HERE MY PLUNKER** [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CH8XgBwDFSp5y9Qd3c1f?p=preview)

It doesn't work because when I click on the button the function test() isn't called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service, as demonstrated in [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jjRZx7iTu1v8ex6BhC3j?p=preview).

The relevant content:

```
app.directive("myDir", function($compile){
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var markdownContent = {};    
    markdownContent.result = element.text();
    markdownContent.result += '<button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" >Hello</button>'; 
    element.replaceWith($compile(markdownContent.result)(scope));
  };
});
```

And the corresponding HTML: `<div my-dir></div>`

This assumes the `test` function is in scope, like so:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function() { console.log("Test!"); };
});
```

---

**Edit**

As Dave mentioned in the comments, the content passed to $compile should have a single root element. You could wrap it in a `<div>`, as Dave suggested. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vl8WcxzQirTWHOjAXrmO?p=preview) is a working version of your Plunk with that edit.

Comment: In that case, mind making a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) with your directive (or fork my Plunk, above) with an example of it not working? Hopefully then I can help :)

Comment: @FlavienBert `$compile` requires a single root element.  So switch the `replaceWith` to :`element.replaceWith($compile('<div>'+markdownContent.result+'</div>')(scope));`

Comment: Thx that work but there is not an other way because if I use this directive in an h1 tag it will be like this : <h1><div> my title </div></h1>. But for SEO reason I don't like this because I'm not sure  it is a good architecture for google SEO. That make sense?

Comment: As it is written, the div will wrap any content which you're placing inside of it. It'd be <div><h1>Title</h1></div>, for example (although you're currently fetching just the .text() at present, and not the html). That said, if you know you'll only have one root element (and not more than one, as was the case when you were appending a button) there is no need for the wrapper div in that case.

Comment: In fact I use this directive like this: <h1> <?php say('hello')?> </h1> and the function say() create this : <span my-directive> content who correspond to the variable hello </span> . So in final I have something like this :  <h1><div>Title</div></h1>